# WCF Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint

Tags: c#, wcf

I have problem when i try to host WCF in console application.

**Am geting exception:**

> Exception:Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for
>   the endpoint with binding WSHttpBinding. Registered base address
>   schemes are [].

**Here is my code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WebServiceProject.Authentication;
using WebServiceProject.Automobili;

namespace ServerHostProject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("--------WCF SERVICE------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Starting WCF Services please wait...");
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------");

            // Host all services

            try
            {
                // base address
                Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:50471/services/");

                // initialize services
                ServiceHost authenticationServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(AuthenticationService));
                ServiceHost automobilServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(AutoService));


                // end points
                authenticationServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IAuthenticationService), new WSHttpBinding(), "");
                automobilServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IAutoService), new WSHttpBinding(), "");

                // metadata exchange
                ServiceMetadataBehavior serviceBehavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
                serviceBehavior.HttpGetEnabled = true;

                authenticationServiceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(serviceBehavior);
                automobilServiceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(serviceBehavior);

                // Open 
                authenticationServiceHost.Open();
                automobilServiceHost.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Service is started now at : {0}", baseAddress);
                Console.ReadKey();

                authenticationServiceHost.Close();
                automobilServiceHost.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception:" + ex.Message);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you don't use your 'baseAddress' anywhere apart from referencing it in the Console towards the end?

Comment: I dont know this is my first time to work with WCF. Give me example

Comment: Well normally where you call 'AddServiceEndpoint' the third paramater (string) which in your code above is currently "" should be your baseAddress variable.

Comment: Yes i see in method definition. I set empty string! Thanks